# telnet connection response if port is closed on firewall

Tags: firewall, networking

If port xxx is not open on a firewall, what would be the telnet response when attempting to open a telnet session from a remote host in network "A" connected via site-to-site VPN with network "B"?

Background:
I can successfully telnet from A to B, but data packets are not received. The firewall admin said he opened the port on the firewall and that fixed the problem.

I would expect that if the port was not open, the telnet connection would have been rejected or timed out.

the connection is telnet  9997.

Comment: Unfortunately, Telnet is off-topic as an application and a protocol above OSI layer-4.

Answer (score 1):

Most firewalls are configured to silently drop packets that they have been configure to deny. A normal response to a closed TCP connection is a RST packet when no firewall or any other access control is in place.